# How do I make a project that uses protocol buffers?

Tags: c++, makefile, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build the [address-book example](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) on Google's protocol buffers.

This is my `Makefile`

```
CFLAGS = -O3
CPP = g++
MSGS = addressbook.pb.o
LIBS=-lprotobuf

%.pb.o: %.proto
        protoc --cpp_out=./ $<
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $*.pb.cc -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

main: $(MSGS) main.o
        $(CPP) $^ -o test $(LIBS)

clean:
        rm test *.pb.* *.o
```

I run `make main`. It correctly does:

```
protoc --cpp_out=./ addressbook.proto
g++ -O3 -c addressbook.pb.cc -o addressbook.pb.o
g++ -O3 -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ addressbook.pb.o main.o -o test -lprotobuf
```

However, I'm getting a bunch of linking errors, they all seem like I'm not linking to `-lprotobuf`, which I clearly am.

Sample error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: addressbook.pb.o:addressbook.pb.cc:(.text+0x3fca): more undefined references to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Mutable[abi:cxx11](google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, google::protobuf::Arena*)' follow
/usr/bin/ld: addressbook.pb.o: in function `tutorial::Person::Person(tutorial::Person const&) [clone .cold]':
addressbook.pb.cc:(.text.unlikely+0x1fe): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::SpaceAllocated() const'
/usr/bin/ld: addressbook.pb.o: in function `tutorial::AddressBook::AddressBook(tutorial::AddressBook const&) [clone .cold]':
addressbook.pb.cc:(.text.unlikely+0x22c): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::SpaceAllocated() const'
/usr/bin/ld: addressbook.pb.o: in function `google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber>::~RepeatedPtrField()':
addressbook.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf16RepeatedPtrFieldIN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberEED2Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf16RepeatedPtrFieldIN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberEED5Ev]+0x4e): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::SpaceAllocated() const'
/usr/bin/ld: addressbook.pb.o: in function `google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<tutorial::Person>::~RepeatedPtrField()':
addressbook.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf16RepeatedPtrFieldIN8tutorial6PersonEED2Ev[_ZN6google8protobuf16RepeatedPtrFieldIN8tutorial6PersonEED5Ev]+0x2f): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ThreadSafeArena::SpaceAllocated() const'
/usr/bin/ld: addressbook.pb.o: in function `google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet* google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadata::mutable_unknown_fields_slow<google::protobuf::UnknownFieldSet>()':
addressbook.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal16InternalMetadata27mutable_unknown_fields_slowINS0_15UnknownFieldSetEEEPT_v[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal16InternalMetadata27mutable_unknown_fields_slowINS0_15UnknownFieldSetEEEPT_v]+0x37): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Arena::AllocateAlignedWithCleanup(unsigned long, std::type_info const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: addressbook.pb.o: in function `google::protobuf::internal::GenericTypeHandler<tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber>::Merge(tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber const&, tutorial::Person_PhoneNumber*)':
addressbook.pb.cc:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal18GenericTypeHandlerIN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberEE5MergeERKS4_PS4_[_ZN6google8protobuf8internal18GenericTypeHandlerIN8tutorial18Person_PhoneNumberEE5MergeERKS4_PS4_]+0xc2): undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::Set(google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::EmptyDefault, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, google::protobuf::Arena*)'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way we can help with the information provided.  Please show (a) the make command line you invoked, (b) the linker command that make invoked, and (c) the *FIRST* few errors that were generated by that command.

I'm not sure what the problem is because I'm not familiar with protobuf.  However, your makefile is quite odd; I recommend you rewrite it like this:

```
CFLAGS = -O3
CPP = g++
LIBS=-lprotobuf

%.pb.cc: %.proto
        protoc --cpp_out=./ $<

%.pb.o: %.pb.cc
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

main: main.o addressbook.pb.o
        $(CPP) $^ -o test $(LIBS)

clean:
        rm test *.pb.*
```

and see if that works any better.  If that doesn't work then it must be something incorrect about your code; at the least it doesn't seem like a makefile or linker invocation problem.

Comment: I have a tule for `*.msg`, which does produce `addressbook.msg` correctly. The `*.msg` rule runs `protoc` on the `.proto` file, which generates & compiles the `.pb.cc` file into `addressbook.msg`

Comment: So, you have a file `.msg` which is actually a compiled object file?  That's, at the very least, very weird and confusing.

Comment: I took your suggestions, but the same issue still stands

Comment: You used `main.o` in the prerequisites list?  Your output above still shows `main.cpp`.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, I `make clean` and run `make main`, in both cases I get the same linker errors.

Comment: Then, the problem is in your code somewhere not in the makefile or link command.  Either there's another library you need to be linking as well, or maybe your code doesn't include some header file that it should be (that would inline these things so they would not be undefined references), or something like that.  I'll have to leave it for someone more familiar with protobuf to make a suggestion.